# trumbowyg plugin won't post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, trumbowyg

I'm using the WYSIWYG editor trumbowyg to supplement the fact that our CMS sucks. The plan is to help out our authors with the HTML without removing the current system they have in place, which is just a plain form with an textarea for article content.

Unfortunately, after activating trumbowyg on the `textarea`, nothing posts with it, no matter what I do.

When I say "nothing posts", I mean that the form worked *before* I added the JavaScript to it, and stopped working after, and I am referring to PHP's `$_POST` array.

Here's what I've tried (although before I was just doing the basics listed on [their website](http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/documentation.html)):

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" method="post">
    <!--other inputs ignored, but present-->
    <textarea name="article"></textarea> <!--this is the textarea in question-->
</form>
```

```js
(function(textarea) {
  textarea.trumbowyg({ closable: true }).on('tbwblur', function() {
    console.log('working'); //This works
    textarea.text(textarea.trumbowyg('html'));
  });
})($("textarea[name=article]"));
```

I *did* start with the following, which didn't work:

```
$("textarea[name=article]").trumbowyg({ closable: true });
```

Comment: Try to remove the phrase "it didn't work" from your vocabulary... forever. Imagine your clients saying this to you. Your response would be the same as mine is now: "What is the 'it' you're talking about, and in what specific way is 'it' not working?" The form isn't submitting? The `.trumbowyg()` isn't firing? What console errors do you get?

Comment: @philtune by "it didn't work", I meant that the POST request didn't go through. Every other form field submitted the information and saved properly in the DB, but the `textarea` did not. I did this both with and without HTML, so it's not an encoding issue. The result was just blank. No JS errors in the console.

Comment: So the plugin is only sending the HTML back to the textarea on `blur` (I'm assuming that's what `'tbwblur'` means)... is your console spitting out `working`? If not, the issue is not in `$_POST` but in the plugin. I'm wondering if hitting `ENTER` is not firing the `blur` and that's the reason. In any event, do you have a live example so we can see what it's doing instead of just guessing?

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar issue and couldn't find a solution anywhere.  After submitting my question to Alex (the author of Trumbowyg), I realized the answer was staring me in the face in the Trumbowyg docs. See https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg/issues/341 .

[Trumbowyg Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnDTu.png)